# Cats-effect and asynchronous IO specifics

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

For few days I have been wrapping my head around cats-effect and IO. And I feel I have some misconceptions about this effect or simply I missed its point.

1. First of all - if IO can replace Scala's Future, how can we create an async IO task? Using `IO.shift`? Using `IO.async`? Is `IO.delay` sync or async? Can we make a generic async task with code like this `Async[F].delay(...)`? Or async happens when we call IO with `unsafeToAsync` or `unsafeToFuture`?
2. What's the point of Async and Concurrent in cats-effect? Why they are separated?
3. Is IO a green thread? If yes, why is there a Fiber object in cats-effect? As I understand the Fiber is the green thread, but docs claim we can think of IOs as green threads.

I would appreciate some clarifing on any of this as I have failed comprehending cats-effect docs on those and internet was not that helpfull...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

> if IO can replace Scala's Future, how can we create an async IO task

First, we need to clarify what is meant as an *async task*. Usually *async* means "does not block the OS thread", but since you're mentioning `Future`, it's a bit blurry. Say, if I wrote:

```
Future { (1 to 1000000).foreach(println) }
```

it would not be *async*, as it's a blocking loop and blocking output, but it would potentially execute on a different OS thread, as managed by an implicit ExecutionContext. The equivalent cats-effect code would be:

```
for {
  _ <- IO.shift
  _ <- IO.delay { (1 to 1000000).foreach(println) }
} yield ()
```

(it's not the shorter version)

So,

- `IO.shift` is used to maybe change thread / thread pool. `Future` does it on every operation, but it's not free performance-wise.
- `IO.delay` { ... } (a.k.a. `IO { ... }`) does *NOT* make anything async and does *NOT* switch threads. It's used to create simple `IO` values from synchronous side-effecting APIs

---

Now, let's get back to *true async*. The thing to understand here is this:

**Every async computation can be represented as a function taking callback.**

Whether you're using API that returns `Future` or Java's `CompletableFuture`, or something like NIO `CompletionHandler`, it all can be converted to callbacks. This is what `IO.async` is for: you can convert any **function taking callback** to an `IO`. And in case like:

```
for {
  _ <- IO.async { ... }
  _ <- IO(println("Done"))
} yield ()
```

`Done` will be only printed when (and if) the computation in `...` calls back. You can think of it as blocking the green thread, but not OS thread.

So,

- `IO.async` is for converting any *already asynchronous* computation to `IO`.
- `IO.delay` is for converting any *completely synchronous* computation to `IO`.
- The code with truly asynchronous computations behaves like it's blocking a green thread.

The closest analogy when working with `Future`s is creating a `scala.concurrent.Promise` and returning `p.future`.

---

> Or async happens when we call IO with unsafeToAsync or unsafeToFuture?

Sort of. With `IO`, *nothing* happens unless you call one of these (or use `IOApp`). But IO does not guarantee that you would execute on a different OS thread or even asynchronously unless you asked for this explicitly with `IO.shift` or `IO.async`.

You can guarantee thread switching any time with e.g. `(IO.shift *> myIO).unsafeRunAsyncAndForget()`. This is possible exactly because `myIO` would not be executed until asked for it, whether you have it as `val myIO` or `def myIO`.

You cannot magically transform blocking operations into non-blocking, however. That's not possible neither with `Future` nor with `IO`.

---

> What's the point of Async and Concurrent in cats-effect? Why they are separated?

`Async` and `Concurrent` (and `Sync`) are type classes. They are designed so that programmers can avoid being locked to `cats.effect.IO` and can give you API that supports whatever you choose instead, such as monix Task or Scalaz 8 ZIO, or even monad transformer type such as `OptionT[Task, *something*]`. Libraries like fs2, monix and http4s make use of them to give you more choice of what to use them with.

`Concurrent` adds extra things on top of `Async`, most important of them being `.cancelable` and `.start`. These do not have a direct analogy with `Future`, since that does not support cancellation at all.

`.cancelable` is a version of `.async` that allows you to also specify some logic to cancel the operation you're wrapping. A common example is network requests - if you're not interested in results anymore, you can just abort them without waiting for server response and don't waste any sockets or processing time on reading the response. You might never use it directly, but it has it's place.

But what good are cancelable operations if you can't cancel them? Key observation here is that you cannot cancel an operation from within itself. Somebody else has to make that decision, and that would happen *concurrently* with the operation itself (which is where the type class gets its name). That's where `.start` comes in. In short,

**`.start` is an explicit fork of a green thread.**

Doing `someIO.start` is akin to doing `val t = new Thread(someRunnable); t.start()`, except it's green now. And `Fiber` is essentially a stripped down version of `Thread` API: you can do `.join`, which is like `Thread#join()`, but it does not block OS thread; and `.cancel`, which is safe version of `.interrupt()`.

---

Note that there are other ways to fork green threads. For example, doing parallel operations:

```
val ids: List[Int] = List.range(1, 1000)
def processId(id: Int): IO[Unit] = ???
val processAll: IO[Unit] = ids.parTraverse_(processId)
```

will fork processing all IDs to green threads and then join them all. Or using `.race`:

```
val fetchFromS3: IO[String] = ???
val fetchFromOtherNode: IO[String] = ???

val fetchWhateverIsFaster = IO.race(fetchFromS3, fetchFromOtherNode).map(_.merge)
```

will execute fetches in parallel, give you first result completed and automatically cancel the fetch that is slower. So, doing `.start` and using `Fiber` is not the only way to fork more green threads, just the most explicit one. And that answers:

> Is IO a green thread? If yes, why is there a Fiber object in cats-effect? As I understand the Fiber is the green thread, but docs claim we can think of IOs as green threads.

- `IO` is like a green thread, meaning you can have lots of them running in parallel without overhead of OS threads, and the code in for-comprehension behaves as if it was blocking for the result to be computed.
- `Fiber` is a tool for controlling green threads explicitly forked (waiting for completion or cancelling).

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by the first example not being asynchronous? When doing some local testing with something like: `Future { (1 to 1000).foreach(println) }; Thread.sleep(1); println("Hello")` things appear to be executing asynchronously, but maybe I'm not quite clear on the definition of asynchronous we're using here.

Comment: @uMdRupert things might appear to interleave non-deterministically, but this appearance can be provided by having enough OS threads to schedule Futures on. OS threads have non-insignificant overhead though, and if you have only one, you'll not see any interleaving. What I meant is that the body of a future would claim one thread at the start of the loop, and not allow any other work on that thread to be done until the loop is finished. Compare to `Future.traverse(1 to 1000)(a => Future(println(a)))` - this one should, from time to time, release a thread and then claim a new one for more work.

Comment: Are all JVM threads supposed to be green? (not OS-issued) Do you mean fibres?