# How to exit from For-Comprehension with IO Monad

Tags: scala, io, cats-effect

I want to make infinite read print cycle with exit when user enter "stop" and make readLn async.

```
import cats.effect.{ExitCode, IO, IOApp, Timer}

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.io.StdIn
import scala.language.postfixOps
import cats.implicits._

object ReadWrite extends IOApp {
  val readLn: IO[String] = IO(StdIn.readLine())
  val readWriteName: IO[Nothing] = for {
    _     <- IO(println("write your name: "))
    name  <- readLn
    _     <- IO(println(s"Hello, $name"))
    t     <- name match {
      case "stop" => ???
      case _      =>  readWriteName
    }
  } yield t

  def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] =
    for {
      _ <- (Timer[IO].sleep(1 millisecond) *> readWriteName).start
      _ <- Timer[IO].sleep(100 second)
    } yield ExitCode.Success
}
```

I tried to use `IO(println(s"Buy Buy"))` but there is error message:

```
Error:(20, 11) type mismatch;
 found   : t.type (with underlying type Unit)
 required: Nothing
  } yield t
```

How to make exit without error?

Also I want to execute IO in another thread, `readLn` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change type of `readWriteName` to `IO[Unit]`.

```
val readWriteName: IO[Unit] = for {
  _     <- IO(println("write your name: "))
  name  <- readLn
  _     <- IO(println(s"Hello, $name"))
  t     <- name match {
    case "stop" => IO(println(s"Buy Buy"))
    case _      =>  readWriteName
  }
} yield t
```

Regarding threads look at [Cats-effect and asynchronous IO specifics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682686/cats-effect-and-asynchronous-io-specifics)

---

Try

```
  val readWriteName: IO[String] = for {
    _     <- IO(println("write your name: "))
    name  <- readLn
    _     <- IO(println(s"Hello, $name"))
    _     <- name match {
      case "stop" => IO(println(s"Buy Buy"))
      case _      =>  readWriteName
    }
  } yield name
```

Comment: Grand thanks! Could you write which type use to send last name to output loop? With Unit in Outer Loop I get Tuple(IO$179256858,IO$1201016791)

Comment: case "stop" => {IO(println(s"Buy Buy")); name}

Comment: Yes, Its work, first entered name returns! Thank you!